# C# DataConcract serialization - Ignore object of certain types in collection

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am making a game editor so I created serialization which serializes List of GameObjects. Now I have some objects in my scene that are specific only for editor (things like gizmo,viewport camera etc.) These are objects that are type of EditorGameObject which inherits from GameObject. How do I mark them as ignored for serialization?
Here's what I'd liek to achieve:

Input:

```
List<GameObject> gameObjects;
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject("gameobject"));
gameObject.Add(new EditorGameObject("editorobject"));
Serialize(gameObjects);
```

Output:

```
List<GameObject> gameobjects = Deserialize();
gameObject contains only one element of type GameObject "gameobject"
```

Comment: Why would you add EditorGameObject instance if you don't want it in your deserialized gameobjects?

Comment: `List<GameObject> gameobjects = Deserialize().Where(go => !(go is EditorGameObject));`

Comment: ... or you could exclude EditorGameObjects before serialization: `Serialize(gameObjects.Where(go => !(go is EditorGameObject)));`

Comment: Dmytro - I serialize  Thanks for useful hint - I already came up with similar solution (removeing objects before serialization and adding after).Those solutions however seem a bit unclean and slow. I am looking for solution clearly with DataContract not manipulating with collections :)